# Use column names as values for Phone Number

Tags: sql, sql-server, union, unpivot, case-statement

I have a table in which has phone numbers split out into separate columns cellphone, homephone, workphone and otherphone. I would like to do some sort of transformation which pulls all the phones into one column but shows the phone relationship in the next column so currently I have data that looks like this:

```
CellPhone  HomePhone  workPhone   OtherPhone
8756785468 8756944858 8756944903  8937944858
```

What I would like to see:

```
TelephoneNumber  TelephoneRelationship
8756785468       Cell
8756944858       Home
8756944903       Work
8937944858       Other
```

My create statement is rather simple:

```
Create Table ods.Telephone(
    CellPhoneNumber varchar(10) null,
    HomePhoneNumber varchar(10) null,
    WorkPhoneNumber varchar(10) null,
    OtherPhoneNumber Varchar(10) null
);
```

Comment: What version of sql server do you have? Recent you can use: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Very similar post [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3000/use-sql-servers-unpivot-operator-to-help-normalize-output/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just one more option via a `CROSS APPLY`

```
Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  Telephone A
 Cross Apply ( values (CellPhoneNumber,'Cell')
                     ,(HomePhoneNumber,'Home')
                     ,(WorkPhoneNumber,'Work')
                     ,(OtherPhoneNumber,'Other')
             ) B(TelephoneNumber,TelephoneRelationship)
```

**Returns**

```
ID  TelephoneNumber TelephoneRelationship
1   8756785468      Cell
1   8756944858      Home
1   8756944903      Work
1   8937944858      Other
```

Comment: I'm upvoting, even though I abhor lines of code that start with a comma.  Haven't seen you around in a while.

Comment: @GordonLinoff We've discussed this before ...  it is easier to comment lines out, and again, a delimiter is just a delimiter.  Would you feel the same if it was a PIPE ?  Funny how important (and personal) style is, for example, my neck tightens-up when I see {...} AS {...}    :)

Comment: I too prefer starting lines with a comma for the same reason. And I know plenty of other people who cringe when they see it. :D

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend unpivoting with `union all`.

This is a standard, cross-RDBMS solution whose syntax is, in my opinion, easier to understand and  remember, and that usually performs as good, or even better than vendor-specific solutions:

```
select id, CellPhoneNumber TelephoneNumber, 'Cell' TelephoneRelationship from Telephone
union all select id, HomePhoneNumber,  'Home'  from Telephone
union all select id, WorkPhoneNumber,  'Work'  from Telephone
union all select id, OtherPhoneNumber, 'Other' from Telephone
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=68fe3002555d4a4b64577865405fb270)**

Sample data:

```
ID | CellPhoneNumber | HomePhoneNumber | WorkPhoneNumber | OtherPhoneNumber
-: | :-------------- | :-------------- | :-------------- | :---------------
 1 | 8756785468      | 8756944858      | 8756944903      | 8937944858
```

Results:

```
id | TelephoneNumber | TelephoneRelationship
-: | :-------------- | :--------------------
 1 | 8756785468      | Cell                 
 1 | 8756944858      | Home                 
 1 | 8756944903      | Work                 
 1 | 8937944858      | Other
```